# What if an advanced alien civilization wanted to save the Earth's ecosystem and help humanity advance as a species?

Tags: internal-consistency, aliens

Let's say that one day an advanced alien civilization comes to Earth and for reasons unknown, they want to save the Earth's ecosystem and biosphere and help humans develop into the next stage of civilization. How exactly would they do that?

I've though of it myself though and there are many things that seems to be a problem. First of all, I think its very clear that many nations would be shocked and paranoid by the mere existence of the aliens, and with that chaos going on, it's reasonable to assume that some nation will probably assume that the aliens are a threat and try to nuke them (Looking at you North Korea). That would make it more difficult for the aliens to help us and perhaps piss them off enough that they'd try to destroy us instead.

And even if the world decided to accept their help, I think the governments wouldn't really listen to the aliens.

The aliens would probably know that in order for the world to get better, humans have to get better as well and assuming that the aliens decide not to brainwash us or something that would be extremely difficult. Given man's nature, humans aren't the most welcoming beings when it cones to change, And that counts for saving the environment as well.

I'll give an example: One of the aliens says to the humans that they should stop using fossil fuels because it destroys the environment and instead they will give us a new form of energy. Of course, there's a problem: if the fossil fuels factories close the companies, and therefore the government, will lose money. The companies wouldn't accept that and most likely they would hire someone to kill the alien before it convinces anyone to use the new energy.

So my question is, "If the aliens were determined to help our planet and species, how would they go about it?"

Note: Brainwashing our species or using force is not an option.

Comment: *"Looking at you"* . . . North Korea? I was not aware that North Korea was the most heavily armed and the most bellicose nation on Earth. And anyway. As they say, the stone age did not end for lack of stone, the bronze age did not end for lack of tin, and the steam age did not end for lack of coal. When the aliens introduce new better cheaper energy production technology then the energy companies will jump on it. Energy companies are not in the business of extracting oil, they are in the business of selling energy to consumers at great profit.

Comment: If they're really that advanced would be powerful enough that our opinion didn't matter, or they'd have enough sense not to try...

Comment: This was explored very well in the first half of *[Childhood's End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End)* by Arthur C. Clarke, 1953. It's a quick read and addresses most elements of the question. After reading, you will see that "using force" must be more clearly defined. Without *force majeure*, there's little point in having them be aliens in the first place.

Comment: This was also explored very well a in a couple of Iain Banks' *[Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture)* novels. Unwilling to compel, Contact representatives had little influence. They floated in the sea of local politics, and groomed personal relationships with key leaders. Results were slow.

Comment: Can you add space and line breaks in your question? The wall of text you have now is really unappealing to read.

Comment: Would help if you explained just what you mean by "next stage of civilization".

Comment: The aliens could leave a message instead of actually showing up. Maybe a bunch of people get an email from the aliens with a recipe for a new power source so that no one actually sees the aliens. The aliens might not say who they were, and people wouldn't know that it was aliens. (Except for the conspiracy theorists who correctly guess it was the aliens)

Comment: What level of morality would these aliens adhere to? On one hand they could strive to make every human's life better, on the other mass killing of the poor starts looking pretty practical.

Comment: Another novel looking at a related idea was The Free Lunch by Spider Robinson.  Although there was limited detail on the proposed solution.

Comment: This question needs quite a few more constraints.  How are the aliens going to make us better?  What methods do they use?  What technology do they have? If you start adding in this context I think the question is salvageable.  But right now any answer would be based solely on assumed/made up facts.

Answer (score 1):

**Enlightened aliens are not going to be obvious.  They will have some art.**

> But being an optimist isn’t about knowing that life used to be worse.
>   It’s about knowing how life can get better. And that’s what really
>   fuels our optimism. Although we see a lot of disease and poverty in
>   our work—and many other big problems that need to be solved—we also
>   see the best of humanity. We spend our time learning from scientists
>   who are inventing cutting-edge tools to cure disease. We talk to
>   dedicated government leaders who are being creative about prioritizing
>   the health and well-being of people around the world. And we meet
>   brave and brilliant individuals all over the world who are imagining
>   new ways to transform their communities.

[image: BILL AND MELINDA GATES]

https://www.panafricanvisions.com/2018/bill-gates-co-chair-bill-melinda-gates-foundation-visit-nigeria/

https://www.gatesfoundation.org

Comment: So Melinda Gates is an alien Contact officer, who decided to help Earth by marrying Bill, convincing him to retire and devote his vast wealth, connections, and organizational skills to philanthropy, sticking with him to subtly guide him toward the most effective targets? And Charles Feeney has been giving away his spare money for most of his life, but only became public (and dramatic, and organized) about it after marrying his second wife Helga. And plenty of other examples.

Answer (score -1):

> What if an advanced alien civilization wanted to
>   1) save the Earth's ecosystem
>   and
>   2) help humanity advance as a species?

Unfortunately the two are mutually exclusive.

If you want humanity to advance they have to learn a lesson, one of those lessons is like burning yourself. You've all been told something is hot and not to touch it, but sooner or later you touch it to find out the truth for yourself. The same is true of destroying the planetary ecosystem. You can clean up after the little humans, stop them hurting themselves, or you can let them learn the lesson.

Sooner or later this lesson is going to be learned the hard way and humanity will have its chance to advance as a species.